# Are all pages within an ASP.Net application ran in the same appdomain?

Tags: asp.net, appdomain

I understand that requests are served by different threads, but do they all come from the same appdomain, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are. This is how one web.config serves the entire scope of the web application. One configuration file per appdomain is a good clue.